# Pandas variable creation using multiple If-else

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, where-clause

Need help with Pandas multiple IF-ELSE statements. I have a test dataset (titanic) as follows:

```
ID  Survived    Pclass  Name    Sex Age
1   0   3   Braund  male    22
2   1   1   Cumings, Mrs.   female  38
3   1   3   Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26
4   1   1   Futrelle, Mrs.  female  35
5   0   3   Allen, Mr.  male    35
6   0   3   Moran, Mr.  male    
7   0   1   McCarthy, Mr.   male    54
8   0   3   Palsson, Master male    2
```

where Id is the passenger id. I want to create a new flag variable in this data frame which has the following rule:

```
if Sex=="female" or (Pclass==1 and Age <18) then 1 else 0.
```

Now to do this I tried a few approaches. This is how I approached first:

```
df=pd.read_csv(data.csv)
for passenger_index,passenger in df.iterrows():
    if passenger['Sex']=="female" or (passenger['Pclass']==1 and passenger['Age']<18):
       df['Prediction']=1
    else:
       df['Prediction']=0
```

The problem with above code is that it creates a Prediction variable in df but with all values as 0.

However if I use the same code but instead output it to a dictionary it gives the right answer as shown below:

```
prediction={}
df=pd.read_csv(data.csv)
for passenger_index,passenger in df.iterrows():
    if passenger['Sex']=="female" or (passenger['Pclass']==1 and passenger['Age']<18):
       prediction[passenger['ID']=1
    else:
       prediction[passenger['ID']=0
```

This gives a dict prediction with keys as ID and values as 1 or 0 based on the above logic.

So why the df variable works wrongly?. I even tried by first defining a function and then calling it. Gave the same ans as first.

So, how can we do this in pandas?.

Secondly, I guess the same can be done if we can just use some multiple if-else statements. I know np.where but it is not allowing to add 'and' condition. So here is what I was trying:

```
df['Prediction']=np.where(df['Sex']=="female",1,np.where((df['Pclass']==1 and df['Age']<18),1,0)
```

The above gave an error for 'and' keyword in where.

So can someone help?. Solutions with multiple approache using np.where(simple if-else like) and using some function(applymap etc) or modifications to what I wrote earlier would be really appreciated.

Also how do we do the same using some applymap or apply/map method of df?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of looping through the rows using `df.iterrows` (which is relatively slow), you can assign the desired values to the `Prediction` column in one assignment:

```
In [27]: df['Prediction'] = ((df['Sex']=='female') | ((df['Pclass']==1) & (df['Age']<18))).astype('int')

In [29]: df['Prediction']
Out[29]: 
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
Name: Prediction, dtype: int32
```

---

For your first approach, remember that `df['Prediction']` represents an entire column of `df`, so `df['Prediction']=1` assigns the value 1 to each row in that column. Since `df['Prediction']=0` was the last assignment, the entire column ended up being filled with zeros.

For your second approach, note that you need to use `&` not `and` to perform an *elementwise* logical-and operation on two NumPy arrays or Pandas NDFrames. Thus, you could use

```
In [32]: np.where(df['Sex']=='female', 1, np.where((df['Pclass']==1)&(df['Age']<18), 1, 0))
Out[32]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

though I think it is much simpler to just use `|` for logical-or and `&` for logical-and:

```
In [34]: ((df['Sex']=='female') | ((df['Pclass']==1) & (df['Age']<18)))
Out[34]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Hi @unutbu. That helps a lot. One doubt. When you said for the first approach, df['Prediction']=1 adds 1 to all rows, am not sure if I understand the reason behind that. I used: 
for passenger_index,passenger in df.iterrows():
    if passenger['Sex']=="female" or (passenger['Pclass']==1 and passenger['Age']<18):
       df['Prediction']=1. 

So essentially it first picks one record at a time and when the condition is true then it adds 1 for that variable else 0. If there was no conditional statement or all records are used at once then I understand the reason. But why here?.

Comment: Like in tools like SAS, SPSS etc, if I write the same condition and say Prediction=1 else prediction=0 it will do as per the condition with a new variable prediction which has 1 if the condition is true else 0. I guess the reason it works is because SAS, SPSS read in one record at a time and then do the operation as mentioned in the code on that record before passing the output. So essentially we also did the same here by calling df.iterrows() to fetch one record at a time and then use the conditional on that?. Why doesn't it work? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even though your `for-loop` is iterating through rows of `df`, your assignment is referencing the entire column, not just one row. Consider, for example, if you were to `print df['Prediction']` you get the entire column, not just a row. `df['Prediction']` is not somehow contextualized to refer to one row just because it is in a `for-loop`. That's not how Python works.

Comment: And just to be clear, `df['Prediction'] = 1` *assigns* 1 to each value in the column, it does not *add* 1 to each value in the column. To add 1 to each value, you'd use `df['Prediction'] += 1`.

Comment: In your `for-loop`, if you replace `df['Prediction']=1` with `passenger['Prediction']=1`, then you *would* be adding a new "column" to the `passenger` row but this would not affect `df` since `passenger` is a *copy* of a row of `df`, not a *view* into the underlying data in `df`. So again, this is just not the right way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Ok. I understand this is not how Pandas works. I was trying to relate it's functionality with other data analysis tools. But in R, I could do a similar thing using apply method and then using the same if-else statement. It creates the right flag. Isn't pandas an add on of R dataframe with more better features?. Or do you think we also have a similar way to do this in pandas using some applymap or apply method and if-else construct?. This is the R code which creates the flag properly: 

c$Flag-> apply(c,1,function(X){ 
        if x[1] == "male" return(1) else return(O); . 
        })
This works

Comment: Yes, you could use `df['Prediction'] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if ((row['Sex']=='female') | ((row['Pclass']==1) & (row['Age']<18))) else 0, axis=1)`, but this will be slower than my original solution if `df` has many rows. The take-away message I hope to impress upon you is that when using NumPy or Pandas, operating row-by-row is never ideal. It is generally faster to perform NumPy/Pandas operations on whole (large) ndarrays or NDFrames because you are pushing more work onto fast underlying C/Fortran functions and doing less with slower Python code.

Comment: And (eek!) pandas is **not** an add-on of R dataframes! pandas is a Python package, and Python and R are two independent languages. As they say in works of fiction, any resemblance is purely coincidental :)

Comment: Yup, Got it. By add on, I meant Pandas is like R+Python :-). Atleast most of the concepts are similar to R users with added functionality. But I do understand your point with respect to speed of execution. Thanks for the help and knowledge!

Comment: I have a problem running the first syntax. When I run 
((df['Sex']=="female") | (df['Pclass']==1 & df.Age<18))
it gives me the following error: 
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

The reason I guess this is happening is in the second condition: 
df['Pclass']==1 & df.Age<18)) where it is taking df['Pclass']==1 as Series (array) while df.Age<18 is bool. But then how is it working for you? I see you got the answer above for the same condition.

Comment: Be careful to include the parentheses: `(df['Pclass']==1) & (df.Age<18)`. Without the parentheses, Python is parsing it as `df['Pclass']==(1 & df.Age)<18`. Notice in the [operator precedence table](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) that `&` has a higher binding precedence than `==` or `<`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. One last question. This helps in creating a flag variable which is binary (True,False) or 1,0 by converting it using astype. What if I want to have customary values in Flag field?. Like if condition is true then Flag="Prediction ready" else "Prediction Not Ready" or any text for that matter?. In that case this method will be difficult to use and I guess then np.where() method is the only way?

Comment: Yes, in that case use `np.where`: `df['baz'] = np.where((df['Sex']=='female') | ((df['Pclass']==1) & (df['Age']<18)), 'Prediction ready', 'Prediction Not Ready')`.