# Pandas error while trying to use and, or statement

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create some boolean variables using `Pandas` but I'm having this error when I try to use "and", "or" evalautions.

The intent of the code is to create a boolean "column" that is only true when `X['XAlerta'] = 1` and `X['# Produtos'] Also = 1`.

`X['Alerta']` is a `1` or `0` variable and `X['# Produtos']` is an integer.

This is my code:

```
X['Possui_Apenas_Alerta'] = X['XAlerta'] == 1 and X['# Produtos'] == 1
```

And this is the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-1e64f0aae21c> in <module>()
 56 X['Flag_Menos_1_Produto'] = X['# Produtos'] <= 1
 57 X['Flag_Mais_3_Produtos'] = X['# Produtos'] >= 3
---> 58 X['Possui_Apenas_Alerta'] = X['XAlerta'] == 1 and X['# Produtos'] == 1
 59 X['Possui_Apenas_Desemprego'] = X['XSeguroDesemprego'] == 1 and X['# Produtos'] == 1
 60 X['Possui_Alerta_Perda_Anuaide'] = X['XSeguroPerdaRoubo'] == 1 and X['XAlerta'] == 1 and X['XRecargaAnuidadeBonificada'] == 1

C:\Users\foray\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
915         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
916                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 917                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
918 
919     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas variable creation using multiple If-else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22504329/pandas-variable-creation-using-multiple-if-else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `&` for biwise `and`, `|` for `or` and `~` for `not`, also add `()`:

```
X['Possui_Apenas_Alerta'] = (X['XAlerta'] == 1) & (X['# Produtos'] == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `=` symbols in a chain like that.

```
X['Possui_Apenas_Alerta'] = (X['XAlerta'] == 1 and X['# Produtos'] == 1)
```

Just having the parentheses around should fix your problem.